# Python Error: Able to run the program from command line but not from IDE

Tags: python, python-2.7, jython

I am trying to use Charm Cryptography library. I have installed the library and I can see the eggs inside the Python/Lib/site-packages. When I run the below program using command line it does but when I try using Eclipse with PyDev plugin it gives me this error. I am using Python 2.7, Windows 7. Please let me know if any other information is required.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\raunak\Documents\workspace1\ABETest\src\test\ABETest.py", line 6, in <module>
    from charm.toolbox.pairinggroup import PairingGroup,GT
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Charm_Crypto-0.42-py2.7-win32.egg\charm\toolbox\pairinggroup.py", line 2, in <module>
    from charm.core.math.pairing import pairing,ZR,G1,G2,GT,init,pair,hashPair,H,random,serialize,deserialize,ismember,order
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


from charm.toolbox.pairinggroup import PairingGroup,GT
from charm.schemes.abenc.abenc_waters09 import CPabe09
group = PairingGroup('SS512')
cpabe = CPabe09(group)
msg = group.random(GT)
(master_secret_key, master_public_key) = cpabe.setup()
policy = '((ONE or THREE) and (TWO or FOUR))'
attr_list = ['THREE', 'ONE', 'TWO']
secret_key = cpabe.keygen(master_public_key, master_secret_key, attr_list)
cipher_text = cpabe.encrypt(master_public_key, msg, policy)
decrypted_msg = cpabe.decrypt(master_public_key, secret_key, cipher_text)
print decrypted_msg == msg
```

**Update:**

```
Python Path from IDE:
['C:\\Users\\raunak\\Documents\\workspace1\\ABETest\\src\\test', 
'C:\\Users\\raunak\\Documents\\workspace1\\ABETest\\src', 
'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\distribute-0.6.35-py2.7.egg', 
'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\Charm_Crypto-0.42-py2.7-win32.egg', 
'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 
'C:\\Python27\\lib', 
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python27', 
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 
'C:\\eclipse\\plugins\\org.python.pydev_2.7.3.2013031601\\pysrc\\pydev_sitecustomize', 
'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip', 
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win']

Python From Command Line:
['C:\\', 
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\distribute-0.6.35-py2.7.egg', 
'C:\\%JYTHONPATH%', 
'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip', 
'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 
'C:\\Python27\\lib', 
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 
'C:\\Python27', 
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Charm_Crypto-0.42-py2.7-win32.egg']
```

Comment: Even I have the same problem, did the problem resolved for you?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a Python path problem.  Compare running:

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

in your command line vs. through PyDev.

Once you find the missing item, you can then add to the python path like any other list, for example:

```
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.join("C:\\", "folder", "file"))
```

Comment: I could only hope if the thing was so simple. I have the Python path configured. I am able to run this both from Command Line and Eclipse

Comment: Were the two paths the same?  It could be that you have extra stuff in one path causing the interpreter to look in the wrong place for something.

Comment: I have added the output of the Python Path from the command Line and IDE.

Comment: Did you try setting the python path in eclipse to the path from the command line?

Comment: I don't think so the error is related to the Python Path. It clearly says that there are certain DLL's missing. I will try the Dependency Walker to track that out.